# why the material not copied

Tags: materials

I have 2 mesh with color white and green. The white (no color on it). I want to copy the green material on to the white mesh. Just i selected the white and then green and in the properties tab i click on copy to material. It copy the material to the mesh but when i click on preview render it show glass material on it. Whats the magic. Any suggestion. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your material uses the [Ray Length](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/light_path.html?highlight=length#light-path-node). The thicker the object is, the more green and dark it gets.

The left object has very little thickness, because you added a [Solidify](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html?highlight=solidify#solidify-modifier) modifier to it. Add more thickness to it, by disabling the solidy modifier to see a similiar color as in the right object.

[image: ray length in material]

Comment: Thanks as always for ur help...

Comment: You're welcome.